# FATAL_ERROR: "continuous.c", line 246: Failed to open audio device

Tags: raspbian, alsa, pocketsphinx

I am looking for a solution for pocketsphinx for a long time. I tried everything

`apt-get remove pulseaudio -y 
aptitude purge pulseaudio -y
apt-get install bison -y
cd /usr/install
tar -xvf sphinxbase-0.8.tar.gz
cd sphinxbase-0.8
./configure
make
make install
tar -xvf pocketsphinx-0.8.tar.gz
cd pocketsphinx-0.8
./configure
make
make install`

There is no file `/etc/modprob.d/alsa-base.config` so I updated `/usr/shared/alsa/alsa.config` uncommenting `load card-specific configuration files (on request)` and also `/lib/modprob.d/aliases.conf` commenting options `snd-usb-audio index=-2`
Every try from various resources I have done. I can record `arecord -f cd -D plughw:1,0 -d 20 test.wav` and play the same file using `aplay test.wav`
my soundcards are

`0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835 - bcm2835 ALSA
                      bcm2835 ALSA
1 [CAMERA         ]: USB-Audio - USB2.0 PC CAMERA
                      ARKMICRO USB2.0 PC CAMERA at usb-3f980000.usb-1.2,high speed`

Every supported libraries are downloaded(Dont'know how many) but still It is not working.
I am using raspbian jessie image.

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to use pocketsphinx-0.8, pocketsphinx-5prealpha is much more accurate.

Audio device for recording is specified with `-adcdev` option:

```
  pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes -adcdev plughw:1,0
```

You can also configure alsa to use plughw:1,0 as default recording device, in that case you would not need `-adcdev`